# Play 2.1: Can't submit chinese character in form submission

Tags: character-encoding, playframework-2.1

I want to submit an article that contains chinese characters, but when I click the submit button, it has no any reaction but the chinese characters become ???? ? 
Play is uft-8 encoding, I don't know why it would be like that

Comment: Write more details. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Can you give us some source (form view and controller submit method at least)? Play is using UTF-8 but what about your files?